# Account sharing among Ubuntu machines

Tags: networking, ubuntu, security, accounts

I'd like a simple and secure system to have allow users in our network to have their account (e.g., 'myname') work on every machine in the network (e.g., such that they could ssh to any machine and have the same userid, mounted smb share).  Any suggestions?

Comment: What central authentication system do you have setup already (AD, LDAP, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer) or NIS to accomplish that. I would recommend LDAP.